# loading.gif is not animated when using loadmask jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins

I've used the Jquery plugin [loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) to mask a table when loading the next page.

Everything works great, but when the mask shows, the loading.gif is static (not spinning), what is causing this?  It is happening in both FF and IE so I don't think it is a browser issue.

If I click on the gif file itself, it animates correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, this is now working, not sure what caused the gif to be static initially.